# Oracle- How to check if streaming functionality is enabled in the database

Tags: oracle, streaming

I need to consume streaming data from an oracle database.

The database team informed me, that the streaming functions are enabled, but how can I make sure of that?

Database version: 19.0.0.0.0

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "streaming functions"?  What technology stack are you trying to use to stream data?

Answer (score 0):

Streams are desupported in Oracle 19c meaning that they can not be used at all. See [Oracle Support Doc 2388741.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=16625742432929&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=FAQ&id=2388741.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=60pg7hxxy_4). It is also mentioned in the [release notes for 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/upgrd/behavior-changes-deprecated-desupport-oracle-database.html#GUID-7E90C2D3-853A-45B2-AC6D-C9326798E82B).